# Model First scaffolding not working in ASP.NET MVC3 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, scaffolding

I am building a controller using scaffolding, from a database model.

The database in the backend is SQL Azure, although I am not sure if that matters.

I entered the connection string, and tested, and it works. I added a new ADO.Net Entity Data Model to my models, and it created the mappings, and I can view the table structure and the FKs when I open the created model, and it looks correct.

I built the solution so the new model is available.

I made sure I have the latest version of Entity Framework, and downloaded the MvcScaffolding from NuGet.

When I add new controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework, I get the following error:

The type 'Website.Models.App.Application' was not mapped.
Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation.
Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

When I try to add the same controller using MvcScaffolding: Controller with read/write actions and views, using EF data access code, I do not get an error at this step, but when I navigate to the Index View of the new controller I get the same error.

Any ideas about what is causing this error? I have seached long for a solution but everything is coming up empty. Thank you.

Comment: Update: I found the following code in the AppModel.Designer.cs , the cs file attached to the edmx model:

public partial class UserApplication : EntityObject

I assume I cannot just remove the EntityObject in there, correct? It seems like all the partial classes representating my tables inherit from EntityObject. What caused that and how do I fix it? Any insights on the problem will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Rename this entity to say applicationtest and compile and try again. I wonder if the name is causing an issue.

Comment: hmm what do you mean by rename the entity? should I rename the table called application in the database to applicationtest and then generate the entity again?

Comment: Open your model and click on the entitys name (on the entity itself) and enter in a new name

Comment: I tried and I am still getting the same error. The last line of the error says:

Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

and my Application does inherit from EntityObject. Isn't that what is causing the error?

Comment: Would it be easy for you to simply delete and recreate your model again? I've seen some info on redoing the model if this error occurs.

Comment: I already tried around 3 or 4 times and every time my Application class inherits from EntityObject in the created model, and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Install Net DbContext Generator, if not available from online templates in your Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

in the entity designer (.edmx file), right click on a blank area, click 'Add Code Generation Item', select 'ADO.NET DbContext Generator' give it a name, click add. >>cant remember why you have to do this :-( but it fixed the same problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

It didn't work; when I clicked on Add Code Generation Item, under the Code category (the other categories were all empty), I had two options: ADO.NET EntityObject Generator and ADO.NET Self-Tracking Entity Generator. I chose the first one and it generated a .tt file, but I got the same problem after trying to scaffold. I don't know if there was supposed to be an ADO.Net DbContext Generator option? If so I couldn't see it.

Comment: first open the designer, then right click>properties, then change the Code Generation Strategy from "Default" to None, then add the code generation item

Comment: Hmm this seems to have broken several things that I'm in the process of trying to fix. The Code Generation Strategy was already on None; I changed it to default to see how that would work. It didn't build because it was complaining about the generator item. I deleted that, and the application built again, but when I tried to add a controller, I am getting an error: Exception calling "GetControllerScaffolders" with "1" argument(s): "The WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called after the pipeline has been closed. Please contact Microsoft Support Services." Now it will not build again.

Comment: Ok I fixed the errors, and downloaded EF from the website instead of NuGet so I have the ADO.NET DbContext Generator item, and followed the steps, but still getting the same initial error. :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably nested your your classes in the main class:

```
static void Class main(string[] args)
{
    public Class YourClass()  // This is the wrong location, it's nested in the main class
    {
       ...
    }
}

public Class YourClass()  // This is the correct location
{
    ...
}
```